# How to properly serve Flask App on Ubuntu via Apache 2 and mod_wsgi? 404 Not Found Error

Tags: ubuntu, flask, apache2, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

My Flask App works great on local loopback with the Flask server, but now I am trying to get apache2 to serve the application on my private 192.168.0.0/24 network (my server's IP is 192.168.0.18).

EDIT3: I have followed most of Mr. Dumpleton's suggestions with the exception of moving the .wsgi out of document root (I plan to do that after all is running properly). I am able to get the [hellow world](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#wsgi-application-script-file) script to run. Any machine on my private LAN can see it via my server's private IP. However when actually trying to get my site to run, a 404 is returned. There are no errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log. I suspect the issue is in my flaskapp.wsgi script. It seems a lot different than the one used for the simple "hello world" page.

Any suggestions? Thank you Stack Overflow

```
root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   www.flaskapp.com
127.0.1.1   server


root@server:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 29 23:27 flaskapp.conf -> ../sites-available/flaskapp.conf


root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jun 30 18:14 flaskapp
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1397 Jun 30 19:02 flaskapp.wsgi

```
root@server:/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp# ls -l
total 92
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun 29 15:19 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       64 Jun 30 00:19 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot 10113 Jun 30 19:12 main.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot 10066 Jun 28 11:54 main.py.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  root       61 Jun 29 15:08 pip-selfcheck.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot    80 Jun 28 16:03 requirements.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7525 Jun 25 11:46 rss_gen27.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7525 Jun 25 11:46 rss_gen27.py.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7520 Jun 25 11:42 rss_gen.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7334 Jun 20 16:01 rss_gen.py.bak
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  robobot  4096 Jun 29 09:24 static
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  robobot  4096 Jun 28 11:53 templates


root@server:/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/flaskapp.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.flaskapp.com
    ServerAlias flaskapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/flaskapp
    <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp python-path=/var/www/flaskapp:/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
    Alias /static /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/static
    <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# cat flaskapp.wsgi 
#!/usr/bin/python
activate_this = '/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
import logging
import os
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskapp")
from flaskapp import app as application
application.secret_key = "random string of chars "


root@server:/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp# cat __init__.py 
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import main


main.py:

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174107/discussion-on-question-by-james-colley-how-to-properly-serve-flask-app-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit belongs to Mr. Dumpleton... here's what worked for me in order to get the flask app served on a private LAN:

```
root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# pwd
/var/www/flaskapp
root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# ls -l
total 96 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun 29 15:19 bin 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      750 Jul  1 00:14 flaskapp.wsgi
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       64 Jun 30 00:19 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  root     4096 Jun 29 15:08 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10113 Jun 30 23:34 main.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot 10113 Jun 30 23:20 main.py.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  root       61 Jun 29 15:08 pip-selfcheck.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot    80 Jun 28 16:03 requirements.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7525 Jun 25 11:46 rss_gen27.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7525 Jun 25 11:46 rss_gen27.py.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7520 Jun 25 11:42 rss_gen.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin  robobot  7334 Jun 20 16:01 rss_gen.py.bak
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  robobot  4096 Jun 29 09:24 static
drwxr-xr-x 2 bin  robobot  4096 Jun 28 11:53 templates

root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# cat __init__.py ; cat flaskapp.wsgi 
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import main
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
import os


this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, this_dir)
activate_this = '/var/www/flaskapp/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
from main import app as application
application.secret_key = "random string here"


Logs are located in /var/log/apache2/error.log

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/flaskapp.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.flaskapp.com
    ServerAlias flaskapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/flaskapp
    <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
    Alias /static /var/www/flaskapp/static
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


root@server:/var/www/flaskapp# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   www.flaskapp.com
127.0.1.1   server

Originally I thought the secret key was not needed in the  .wsgi file and in the file with the routes as well... However I needed the key in both places
```